# I'm trying to build a E-commerce website using Spring. I have added the cart functionality. But when I click on order button the cart is not updated

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, jsp

CartItemController

```
    package com.emusicstore.controller;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.ui.Model;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PathVariable;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;

import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;

@Controller
@RequestMapping("/cart")
public class CartItemController {
    @RequestMapping
    public String get(HttpServletRequest request)
    {
        return "redirect:/cart/"+request.getSession(true).getId(); //Session id is used as cart Id

    }

    @RequestMapping(value="/{cartId}",method= RequestMethod.GET)
    public String getCart(@PathVariable(value="cartId") String cartId, Model model)
    {
        model.addAttribute("cartId",cartId);
        return "cart";
    }

}
```

CartController.java

```
    package com.emusicstore.controller;

import com.emusicstore.dao.CartDao;
import com.emusicstore.dao.ProductDao;
import com.emusicstore.model.Cart;
import com.emusicstore.model.CartItem;
import com.emusicstore.model.Product;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;
import org.springframework.http.HttpStatus;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.*;

import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;

@Controller
@RequestMapping("/rest/cart")
//Rest services we need to start,starts with rest in path
public class CartController {

    @Autowired
    private CartDao cartDao;

    @Autowired
    private ProductDao productDao;

    @RequestMapping(value="/{cartId}",method= RequestMethod.GET)
    public @ResponseBody Cart read(@PathVariable(value ="cartId") String cartId)
    {
        return cartDao.read(cartId);
    }
            //@Response Body returns a model object in JSON Format
    //Cart object which is returned is put into @ResponseBody and because of jackson deendendency The sping converts the object
    //to JSON format and puts in @ResponseBody


    //Reverse Process
    @RequestMapping(value="/{cartId}",method=RequestMethod.PUT)
    @ResponseStatus(value= HttpStatus.NO_CONTENT)
    public void update(@PathVariable(value="cartId") String cartId, @RequestBody Cart cart)
    {
        cartDao.update(cartId,cart);
    }
//Read something-GET
//Post something in UrL=POST
//Update info-PUT

    @RequestMapping(value="/{cartId}",method=RequestMethod.DELETE)
    @ResponseStatus(value=HttpStatus.NO_CONTENT)
    public void delete(@PathVariable(value="cartId")String cartId)
    {
        cartDao.delete(cartId);
    }

    @RequestMapping(value="/add/{productId}",method=RequestMethod.PUT)
    @ResponseStatus(value=HttpStatus.NO_CONTENT)
    public void addItem(@PathVariable(value="productId")String productId, HttpServletRequest request)
    {
        String sessionId=request.getSession(true).getId();
        Cart cart=cartDao.read(sessionId);

        if(cart==null)
        {
            cart=cartDao.create(new Cart(sessionId));
        }
        Product product=productDao.getProductById(productId);
        if(product==null)
        {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException(new Exception());
        }
        cart.addCartItem(new CartItem(product));

        cartDao.update(sessionId,cart);

    }
    @RequestMapping(value="/remove/{productId}",method = RequestMethod.PUT)
    @ResponseStatus(value=HttpStatus.NO_CONTENT)
    public void removeItem(@PathVariable String productId, HttpServletRequest request)
    {
        String sessionId=request.getSession(true).getId();
        Cart cart=cartDao.read(sessionId);
        if(cart==null)
        {
            cart=cartDao.create(new Cart(sessionId));
        }
        Product product=productDao.getProductById(productId);
        if(product==null)
        {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException(new Exception());
        }
        cart.removeCartItem(new CartItem(product));

        cartDao.update(sessionId,cart);
    }

    @ExceptionHandler(IllegalArgumentException.class)
    @ResponseStatus(value= HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST,reason="Illegal request, Please your verify your payload")
    public void handleClientErrors(Exception e)
    {

    }

    @ExceptionHandler(Exception.class)
    @ResponseStatus(value= HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR,reason="Internal Server Error")
    public void handleServerErrors(Exception e)
    {

    }
}
```

CartDaoImpl.java

```
    package com.emusicstore.dao.impl;

import com.emusicstore.dao.CartDao;
import com.emusicstore.model.Cart;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;
@Repository
public class CartDaoImpl implements CartDao {
    private Map<String, Cart> listOfCarts;

    public CartDaoImpl()
    {
        listOfCarts=new HashMap<String, Cart>();
    }

    @Override
    public Cart create(Cart cart) {
        if(listOfCarts.keySet().contains(cart.getCartId())){
            throw new IllegalArgumentException(String.format("Cannot create a cart. A cart " +
                    "with given id(%)"+"already"+"exists",cart.getCartId()));
        }
        listOfCarts.put(cart.getCartId(),cart);
        return cart;
    }

    @Override
    public Cart read(String cartId) {
        return listOfCarts.get(cartId);
    }

    @Override
    public void update(String cartId, Cart cart) {
        if(!listOfCarts.keySet().contains(cartId))
        {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException(String.format("Cannot update cart. The cart with the given id(%)" +
                    "does not"+"exists.",cart.getCartId()));
        }
        listOfCarts.put(cartId,cart);
    }

    @Override
    public void delete(String cartId) {
        if(!listOfCarts.keySet().contains(cartId))
        {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException(String.format("Cannot delete cart. A cart with the given id(%)"
            +"does not exists",cartId));
        }
        listOfCarts.remove(cartId);
    }
}
```

viewProduct.jsp

```
<%@taglib prefix="form" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form" %>
<%@taglib prefix="spring" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags" %>
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>
<%@include file="/WEB-INF/views/template/header.jsp" %>

<div class="container-wrapper">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="page-header">
            <h1>Product Detail</h1>

            <p class="lead">Here is the detailed information of the products</p>
        </div>

        <div class="container-fluid" ng-app="cartApp">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-5">
                   <img src="<c:url value="/resources/images/${product.productId}.png"/>" alt="image" style="width:100%"/>
<!-- ;height:300px-->
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-5">
                    <h3>${product.productName}</h3>
                    <p>${product.productDescription}</p>
                    <p>

                        <strong>Manufacturer</strong>:${product.productManufacturer}

                    </p>
                    <p>
                        <strong>Category</strong>:${product.productCategory}
                    </p>
                    <p>
                        <strong>Condition</strong>:${product.productCondition}
                    </p>
                    <p>
                    <h4>${product.productPrice} USD</h4>
                    </p>

                    <br/>

                    <c:set var="role" scope="page" value="${param.role}"/>
                    <c:set var="url" scope="page" value="/productList"/>
                    <c:if test="${role='admin'}">
                        <c:set var="url" scope="page" value="/admin/productInventory"/>
                    </c:if>

                    <p ng-controller="cartCtrl">
                        <a href="<c:url value="${url}"/>" class="btn btn-default">Back</a>
                        <a href="#" class="btn btn-warning btn-large"
                           ng-click="addToCart('${product.productId}')"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-shopping-cart"></span>Order Now</a>
                        <a href="<spring:url value="/cart"/>" class="btn btn-default"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-hand-right"></span>View Cart</a>
                    </p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<script scr="<c:url value="/resources/js/controller.js"/>"></script>
<%@include file="/WEB-INF/views/template/footer.jsp" %>
```

cart.jsp

```
    <%@ taglib prefix="spring" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags" %>
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>
<%@include file="/WEB-INF/views/template/header.jsp" %>
<div class="container-wrapper">
    <div class="container">
        <section>
            <div class="jumbotron">
                <div class="container">
                    <h1>Cart</h1>

                    <p>All the selected products in your shopping cart</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </section>
        <section class="container" ng-app="cartApp">
            <div ng-controller="cartCtrl" ng-init="initCartId('${cartId}')">
            <div>
                <a class="bnt btn-danger pull-left" ng-click="clearCart()"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove-sign"></span>Clear Cart</a>

            </div>

            <table class="table table-hover">
                <tr>
                    <th>Product</th>
                    <th>Unit Price</th>
                    <th>Quantity</th>
                    <th>Price</th>
                    <th>Action</th>
                </tr>
                <tr ng-repeat="item in cart.cartItems">
                    <td>{{item.product.ProductName}}</td>
                    <td>{{item.product.ProductPrice}}</td>
                    <td>{{item.quantity}}</td>
                    <td>{{item.totalPrice}}</td>
                    <td><a href="#" class="label label-danger" ng-click="removeFromCart(item.product.productId)">
                       <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></span>remove</a></td>
                </tr>

                <tr>
                    <th></th>
                    <th></th>
                    <th>Grand Total</th>
                    <th>grandTotal</th>
                </tr>

            </table>
            <a href="<spring:url value="productList"/>"class="btn btn-default">Continue Shopping</a>
            </div>
        </section>

    </div>
</div>

<script src="<c:url value="/resources/js/controller.js"/>"></script>
<%@include file="/WEB-INF/views/template/footer.jsp" %>
```

controller.js

```
    var cartApp=angular.module("cartApp",[]);
cartApp.controller("cartCtrl",function($scope,$http){
    $scope.refreshCart=function(cartId){
        $http.get('/eMusicStore_war_exploded/rest/cart/'+$scope.cartId).success(function (data){
           $scope.cart=data;
        });
    };

    $scope.clearCart=function(){
        $http.delete('/eMusicStore_war_exploded/rest/cart/'+$scope.cartId).success($scope.refreshCart($scope.cartId));
    };

    $scope.initCartId=function(cartId){
        $scope.cartId=cartId;
        $scope.refreshCart(cartId);
    };

    $scope.addToCart=function(productId)
    {
        $http.put('/eMusicStore_war_exploded/rest/cart/add/'+productId).success(function (data){
           $scope.refreshCart($http.get('/eMusicStore_war_exploded/rest/cart/cartId'));
           alert('Product successfully added to cart!')
        });
    };

    $scope.removeFromCart=function(productId){
        $http.put('/eMusicStore_war_exploded/rest/cart/remove/'+productId).success(function(data){
            $scope.refreshCart($http.get('eMusicStore_war_exploded/rest/cart/cartId'));
        });

    };
});
```

When I try to execute it, I'm getting the product page but after presssing the order now button the url changes to http://localhost:8004/eMusicStore_war_exploded/productList/viewProduct/1#
where 1 is productId but after that there isn't any popup stating that order has been placed and when I view the cart I'm getting only the varibale name which I used in jsp script and not the value. When I tried to debug I found that the ng-click from viewProduct.jsp is not performing any action. Please help me fix this...[image]

Comment: Did you include angular js library in the jsp  ? see this https://www.w3schools.com/angular/tryit.asp?filename=try_ng_default

Comment: Cool dude. The cart.jsp page is now working fine. But still when I click orderNow button the cart is not updated..

Comment: Thanks Bro now everything's working fine.                                                                <script src="<c:url value="/resources/js/controller.js"/>"></script> I made of type for src as scr. Now it's working...

Comment: you are welcome i am happy it helped